# Can fonts have patterns instead of colors?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to give some text zebra stripes, for example, or polka dots? Or is it possible to mask an image with text to provide the same effect?

I can't find any questions about this, and don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can, with `pstricks`and more specifically with `pst-text` and `pst-fill`. Here are two examples:

- From `pst-text` doc:
  [image]
- From  [pstricks web page](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi):
  [image]

Comment: Of course, just because you *can* do it, doesn't mean you *should* do it!

Comment: @Thruston I assume you mean you should have flashing animated text zooming in from off page.

Comment: I didn't do whatever personally. I think it's only for demonstrative purposes. Well, actually, I'd like to see Donald T.  filled with myriads of little bats…